# Code stops executing Ban discord bot, python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a code:

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@Client.command()
async def Ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason="Nie podano"):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("Nie możesz zbanować sam siebie")
        return
    message = f"Zostałeś zbanowany na serwerze {ctx.guild.name}\nPowód: {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} Został zbanowany!\nPowód: {reason}")
    print('a')
    await member.ban(reason = reason)
    print('b')
```

Everything is done, but after displaying the letter "a" in the console, the script stops running

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with your code if you have any errors then please mention them or if you have a error handler try to remove it by commenting and then try to get the error.

```py
await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
```

I have done plenty of discord.py but never faced the problem of code being stopping. Lastly (I don't think this would be the problem) you might want to check the python version you have and the one discord.py requires.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed after the code was changed. I uninstalled and installed the library, the problem continues.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/830859187378454559/884835658353483866/unknown.png

Check the image. I don't exactly get why you are having a problem like code stoping.

Comment: I also do not know, when I wrote the function from 0, the error also appeared

Comment: Yes It would be very helpful if you could tell what error you are having. 
Since I am on  phone right now and my bot dosen't have members intent. I tried 
`user.ban()` But it gives me the error that user object has no attribute ban. 
So the person below might be right that you need members intent.  But the image i showed you was performed without members intent

Comment: Mistake, in the sense that I can't ban anyone

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your bot has a Members intent and enough rights to ban members.

To add a Members intent, do :

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
```

before instantiating the bot and then :

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='...', intents=intents)
```

To give your bot ban rights better make it an admin via permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a bug